# Version creation failed: user-provided package test_code.tar.gz failed to install

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I'm implementing keras model for object detection. The training code for which is successfully packaged and has resulted in a model_weights.hdf5 file. In order to get online prediction for test images, I'm following custom prediction routine suggested by GC ai-platform to serve model & its artifact code in cloud for prediction. During versioning of model when i'm using default python 2.7; Although a version is successfully created but when tested by providing JSON format numpy array converted to list, it throws.

```
{
  "error": "Prediction failed: unknown error."
}
```

The code seems to output list of bboxes & labels when ran locally; Furthermore to ensure, I deliberately checked through MyPredictor class (defined as Custom Prediction routine @ https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/custom-prediction-routines#deploy_your_custom_prediction_routine) to spot any error, lapse in code.

Post that i tried to create another version with --python-version flag 3.5, It's now even failing to create a Version, with an error:

`Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: "Failed to load model: User-provided package test_code-0.1.tar.gz failed to install: Command '['python-default', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--target=/tmp/custom_lib', '--no-cache-dir', '-b', '/tmp/pip_builds', '/tmp/custom_code/test_code-0.1.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Error code: 0)"`

I followed Custom prediction routine example for writing my predictor.py module holding MyPredictor class as follows:

```
class MyPredictor(object):
  def __init__(self, config, model_rpn, model_classifier):
    self._config =config
    self._model_rpn= model_rpn
    self._model_classifier= model_classifier

  def format_img_size(self, img):
    img_min_side = float(self._config['im_size'])
    (height,width,_) = img.shape
    if width <= height:
        ratio = img_min_side/width
        new_height = int(ratio * height)
        new_width = int(img_min_side)
    else:            
        ratio = img_min_side/height
        new_width = int(ratio * width)
        new_height = int(img_min_side)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (new_width, new_height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    return img, ratio

  def format_img_channels(self, img):
    img = img[:, :, (2, 1, 0)]
    img = img.astype(np.float32)
    img[:, :, 0] -= self._config['img_channel_mean'][0]
    img[:, :, 1] -= self._config['img_channel_mean'][1]
    img[:, :, 2] -= self._config['img_channel_mean'][2]
    img /= self._config['img_scaling_factor']
    img = np.transpose(img, (2, 0, 1))
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    return img

  def format_img(self, img):        
    img, ratio = self.format_img_size(img)
    img = self.format_img_channels(img)
    return img, ratio

  def get_real_coordinates(self, ratio, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    real_x1 = int(round(x1 // ratio))
    real_y1 = int(round(y1 // ratio))
    real_x2 = int(round(x2 // ratio))
    real_y2 = int(round(y2 // ratio))
    return (real_x1, real_y1, real_x2 ,real_y2)

  def preprocess(self, inputs):
    X, ratio = self.format_img(inputs)        
    if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'tf':
        X = np.transpose(X, (0, 2, 3, 1))            
    [Y1, Y2, F] = self._model_rpn.predict(X)
    R = roi_helpers.rpn_to_roi(Y1, Y2, self._config, K.image_dim_ordering(), overlap_thresh=0.7)

    R[:, 2] -= R[:, 0]
    R[:, 3] -= R[:, 1]

    bboxes = {}
    probs = {}
    bbox_threshold = 0.8

    class_mapping= self._config['class_mapping']

    for jk in range(R.shape[0]//self._config['num_rois'] + 1):
        ROIs = np.expand_dims(R[self._config['num_rois']*jk:self._config['num_rois']*(jk+1), :], axis=0)
        if ROIs.shape[1] == 0:
            break
        if jk == R.shape[0]//self._config['num_rois']:                
            curr_shape = ROIs.shape
            target_shape = (curr_shape[0],self._config['num_rois'],curr_shape[2])
            ROIs_padded = np.zeros(target_shape).astype(ROIs.dtype)
            ROIs_padded[:, :curr_shape[1], :] = ROIs
            ROIs_padded[0, curr_shape[1]:, :] = ROIs[0, 0, :]
            ROIs = ROIs_padded
        [P_cls, P_regr] = self._model_classifier.predict([F, ROIs])            
        for ii in range(P_cls.shape[1]):
            if np.max(P_cls[0, ii, :]) < bbox_threshold or np.argmax(P_cls[0, ii, :]) == (P_cls.shape[2] - 1):
                continue                
            cls_name = class_mapping[np.argmax(P_cls[0, ii, :])]                
            if cls_name not in bboxes:
                bboxes[cls_name] = []
                probs[cls_name] = []                    
            (x, y, w, h) = ROIs[0, ii, :]                
            cls_num = np.argmax(P_cls[0, ii, :])                
            try:
                (tx, ty, tw, th) = P_regr[0, ii, 4*cls_num:4*(cls_num+1)]
                tx /= self._config['classifier_regr_std'][0]
                ty /= self._config['classifier_regr_std'][1]
                tw /= self._config['classifier_regr_std'][2]
                th /= self._config['classifier_regr_std'][3]
                x, y, w, h = roi_helpers.apply_regr(x, y, w, h, tx, ty, tw, th)
            except:
                pass
            bboxes[cls_name].append([self._config['rpn_stride']*x, self._config['rpn_stride']*y, self._config['rpn_stride']*(x+w), self._config['rpn_stride']*(y+h)])
            probs[cls_name].append(np.max(P_cls[0, ii, :]))
    return [bboxes, probs]

  def postprocess(self, bounding_boxes, probabilities):
    all_dets=[]
    bboxes=bounding_boxes
    probs=probabilities        
    for key in bboxes:
        bbox = np.array(bboxes[key])
        new_boxes, new_probs = roi_helpers.non_max_suppression_fast(bbox, np.array(probs[key]), overlap_thresh=0.5)
        for jk in range(new_boxes.shape[0]):
            (x1, y1, x2, y2) = new_boxes[jk,:]
            coord_list= list(self.get_real_coordinates(ratio, x1, y1, x2, y2))
            all_dets.append((key,100*new_probs[jk],coord_list))
    return all_dets

  def predict(self, instances):
    inputs = np.asarray(instances)
    [bboxes, probs]= self.preprocess(inputs)        
    results = self.postprocess(bboxes, probs)
    return results.tolist()

  @classmethod
  def from_path(cls, model_dir):        
    model_path= os.path.join(model_dir,'model_frcnn.hdf5')
    num_features = 1024       
    config ={'verbose': True, 'network': 'resnet50', 'use_horizontal_flips': False, 'use_vertical_flips': False, 'rot_90': False, 'anchor_box_scales': [128, 256, 512], 'anchor_box_ratios': [[1, 1], [0.7071067811865475, 1.414213562373095], [1.414213562373095, 0.7071067811865475]], 'im_size': 600, 'img_channel_mean': [103.939, 116.779, 123.68], 'img_scaling_factor': 1.0, 'num_rois': 32, 'rpn_stride': 16, 'balanced_classes': False, 'std_scaling': 4.0, 'classifier_regr_std': [8.0, 8.0, 4.0, 4.0], 'rpn_min_overlap': 0.3, 'rpn_max_overlap': 0.7, 'classifier_min_overlap': 0.1, 'classifier_max_overlap': 0.5, 'class_mapping': {'cake': 0, 'donuts': 1, 'dosa': 2, 'bg': 3}, 'model_path': './model_frcnn.hdf5', 'base_net_weights': 'resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5'}        
    class_mapping = config['class_mapping']
    if 'bg' not in class_mapping:
        class_mapping['bg'] = len(class_mapping)        
    class_mapping = {v: k for k, v in class_mapping.items()}
    config['class_mapping']= class_mapping        
    input_shape_img = (None, None, 3)
    input_shape_features = (None, None, num_features)        
    img_input = Input(shape=input_shape_img)
    roi_input = Input(shape=(config['num_rois'], 4))
    feature_map_input = Input(shape=input_shape_features)       
    shared_layers = nn.nn_base(img_input, trainable=True)        
    num_anchors = len(config['anchor_box_scales']) * len(config['anchor_box_ratios'])
    rpn_layers = nn.rpn(shared_layers, num_anchors)
    classifier = nn.classifier(feature_map_input, roi_input, config['num_rois'], nb_classes=len(class_mapping), trainable=True)
    model_rpn = Model(img_input, rpn_layers)        
    model_classifier = Model([feature_map_input, roi_input], classifier)        
    model_rpn.load_weights(model_path, by_name=True)
    model_classifier.load_weights(model_path, by_name=True)
    model_rpn.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')
    model_classifier.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')

    return cls(config, model_rpn, model_classifier)
```

I'm not able to reckon the error and even doubting the approach i've been following all along; would really appreciate any help/corrections in this. Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: yes, the later part regarding versioning fail is solved, it was a TF runtime version issue i noticed on getting similar error on my notebook & extended logs.
Changing runtime-version from 1.13 to 1.5 successfully created one. But the prediction fail error persists, i doubt its hailing from my implementation of custom prediction template.

Comment: For me the issue was a big related to `NLTK`. The platform is bad so to get it to work you just have to figure out a point where the code runs without error and then keep adding lines to it and see where the error finally happens. It's annoying

Comment: Right! even at one instance, due to a subtle diff. in scipy & cv2's read format made a difference of throwing an array of prediction at once and an empty array at times. Forced me to run it line by line to figure out, followed by couple of prints validating output types & shapes. You could try the same if you're running locally or on cloudshell. And anyway i found turning on ```stderr & stdout logging```  with ```--enable-console-logging``` during model resource creation helpful.

Comment: For me in the custom prediction routine console logging didn’t work. Idk why

Comment: I get exactly the same error even after changing the runtime-version... I ran it locally and it seems like there is no error...

Comment: Yes i realized, only runtime change didn't mitigate the error in my case. You do have to mention version numbers for other required packages that don't come inbuilt in gcloud environment with `TF runtime version 1.5`. As in my case i changed `REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['keras']` to `['keras==2.2.0' ]` in `setup.py` file to keep dependency versions consistent across both where code runs well (i.e., locally) and in cloud while packaging.
So for example my `setup.py` had:
`REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['keras==2.2.0', 'h5py==2.8.0', 'opencv-contrib-python==3.4.0.12', 'scipy==1.1.0']`
please check.